# Symfony 2, Is it possible to define route with condition?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I would like to have action in controller with if..else statement, which analyze route and acts accordingly. Is this possible?

routes: `blog\post\{tag} or blog\post.`
tag is an array, thus most probably it looks like ?tag=1,2,3,4,51

```
controller action diplaypost()
{
if (!isset($_GET['tag'])) {do smth; //case of route blog\post}
else {do smth; //case of route blog\post\{tag} }
}
```

Comment: This might apply: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions but I think all you really need is to give tag a default value of null.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current route's name this way:

```
$route = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

You can now use `$route` for whatever logic you need.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do (what are the actions you're performing) with each route? Is the first one filtering a list of posts by tag whereas the second is simply showing all posts? In reality these are two routes going to the same action and would be defined as

```
blog_post:
    path: blog/post
    defaults: { _controller: YourController:YourAction, tag: null }

blog_post_tag:
    path: blog/post/{tag}
    defaults: { _controller: YourController:YourAction }
```

Then your controller action would be:

```
public function yourAction($tag = null)
{
    if ($tag === null) {
        // something
    } else {
        // something else
    }
}
```

While @Elnur Abdurrakhimov is correct with his answer, doing it this way is usually and indication of a code smell and should be avoided if possible.

Also in your example you're using the super global `$_GET` which you shouldn't do in Symfony 2 and should use the `Request` object. [See the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-as-a-controller-argument) for how to do this in a controller method.

Comment: You don't really need to separate these routes. You can have only one and still make it working

Comment: How to make this is tag is an array? Most probably in URL it looks like ?tag=1,2,3,4,51

Comment: You could only do this automatically by writing your own [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html). More simply, just do `$tags = explode(',', $tag)` in your action. Passing arrays via query parameters is a bit clunky natively, e.g. `?tag[]=1&tag=[]2&tag[]=3`.